# Cannot create a service on kernel.terminate

Tags: symfony

After upgrading from Symfony 2.5 to 2.6, I'm unable to render twig templates using the `asset` helper on `kernel.terminate`. Here is a simplified test case:

```php
class TestController extends Controller
{

    public function myAction(Request $request)
    {
        $this->container->get('event_dispatcher')->addListener(KernelEvents::TERMINATE, function() {
            $service = $this->container->get('templating.helper.assets');
            $url = $service->getUrl('logo.png');
        });

        return new Response('Finished');
    }
}
```

The following exception is thrown:

```
InactiveScopeException in *** line ***: You cannot create a service ("templating.helper.assets") of an inactive scope ("request").
```

With Symfony 2.5, this is working well. I cannot find anything significant in the [changelog from 2.5 to 2.6](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/compare/2.5...v2.6.1).

Comment: Are you sure this worked in 2.5?  The TERMINATE event is not even generated until the response is sent to the browser.  Just seems strange to be templating.  But if you are sure then open an issue on github.  Probably some inadvertent code change.

Comment: @Cerad My mistake. It doesn't work in 2.5 either, the scope "request" doesn't seem to be available after the response has been sent. But still, I need to send HTML formated emails then.

Comment: Use the RESPONSE event.  Set the priority so your listener get's called last.

Comment: @Cerad Rendering and sending mails can take some time, and I prefer sending back the response to the client as early as possible, hence the use of the Terminate event.

Answer (score 1):

It makes no sense to access the request after you have sent away the response. You are doing something weird...

If you need to send HTML formatted emails you can use the [memory spool](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email/spool.html) which will send the emails after the event.

If you are running some kind of background task you should consider using a different CPU thread. If you run the background task with the same thread you serve HTTP requests then new requests are waiting for the background task to finish. See [this resource](http://developer.happyr.com/real-asynchronous-events-with-symfony2) under PHP-FPM pools for more info about this.

The fact is that you don't need **the** request for doing templating. You need **a** request. You can do something like this:

```
$request = new Request(); //You may want to set locale and domain etc..
$this->container->enterScope('request');
$this->container->set('request', $request, 'request');
```

Comment: In fact, using **the** request is easier because I don't have to set the locale, domain, etc. again. I ended using the same $request object:
`$eventDispatcher->addListener(KernelEvents::TERMINATE, function() use ($request) { [...] }); `